# How can I determine whether a intermediate results has or has no data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, dimensions, tensor

How can I implement "if there exist items in a Tensor then calculate the average value of it, else assign it a certain value"?
take **tf.gather_nd()** for example choosing some rows from source_tensor with **shape (?, 2)**

```
result = tf.gather_nd(source_tensor, indices)
```

should get the items from source_tensor according indices, but if indices is **am empty list []**, tf.gather_nd will, the program will continue and there is nothing in **result**.

So I wonder that is there a way to determine if the **result** is empty (that is it has no data) when building the computational graph of tensorflow? and if so, I want to assign it constant value manually.

Because what I'm going to do next is

```
tf.reduce_mean(result)
```

if the **result** has no data, tf.reduce_mean(result) will produce **nan**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this via `tf.cond`, which executes one of two branches depending on some condition. I haven't tested the below code so please report whether it works.

```
mean = tf.cond(tf.size(result), lambda: tf.reduce_mean(result), lambda: some_constant)
```

The idea is to check whether `result` contains any items via `tf.size` (should return 0 if `result` is empty). You might need to convert it to a boolean condition explicitly, i.e. use `tf.cast(tf.size(result), tf.bool)` instead.

Comment: my_mean = tf.cond(tf.cast(tf.size(result), tf.bool),
                     lambda: tf.reduce_mean(result, axis=0),
                     lambda: tf.constant(xxx, dtype=tf.float32))
This works perfectly, thank you.~